# HTML select option value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option :

```
<select>
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="vw">VW</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want is that whatever option I select from the dropdown, the value in the select should always be "select".
Thanks.

Comment: set the `value` attribute of al the `<option>`'s to `select`?

Comment: You should explain what you really mean and why. Phrases like “the value in the select” are vague and ambiguous. And it really sounds like you would want to create a `select` element where all choices have the same effect – why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
<select id="yourselect">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="vw">VW</option>
</select>


<script>
   var s = document.getElementById('yourselect');
   s.onchange = function() {
      s.selectedIndex = 0;  // on change event always select the first option
   }
</script>
```

---

Example Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8geek/

Comment: document.getElementById('youselect'); should be document.getElementById('yourselect');

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for an `onchange` event, in that listener you set the currently selected option to `Select` dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Like Jukka mentioned, it seems like you want a select element where all the choices have the same effect? However, you should at least store the the chosen option.

Maybe this is something you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/NfRRM/

Comment: The effect should not be the same. I am calling different functions on selection of different options. Only what option I have selected should not be reflected.